# What is the most performant Atmosphere transport after websockets?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, atmosphere

I am using JBoss 7.1.1FINAL and thus I am stuck without websocket support.  I have recently gone through the hoops of installing support for the JBoss native Comet support, and I am not sure how ensure it's being used.

Question #1) is 'Native Comet' (server) just the implementation for 'long-polling' (client) support?

Question #2) is 'streaming' (client) better than (aka, more performant) than long-polling (with or without 'Native Coment' on the back-end)?

**tl;dr** - what transport should I attempt to use when websocket is not an option with Atmosphere + JBoss 7.1.1FINAL?

Comment: why not go with WildFly 8, which has proper support for websockets? WildFly is renamed jboss as project.

Comment: It's a fair point, but in this case I'm working on an enterprise application where change is discouraged unless necessary.  Moving to WildFly 8 would be a migration effort which far exceeds the addition of a messaging/push feature(s).  If I were to change, I'd probably just ditch JBoss and move to Jetty where this whole issue becomes moot as well.  Again, same issue with the migration effort.

Comment: Other option would be to move to EAP 6, commercially supported version of AS7, which got native support for web sockets as part of 6.2.

Comment: I've actually considered that as well, but again - the migration effort would still be non-trivial from a dev-ops perspective.  I was hoping to simply take advantage of the "best" transport for now and await the day when we migrate to (most likely) Jetty.